# How can I show which question a user is on when taking my quiz?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a quiz application and need some help with a couple of things.

I would like for users to be able to see Which question they are currently on (ex. 7 out of 10), their current score (ex. 3 correct out of 4), and to receive feedback about their answer (ex. correct answers display "correct" and incorrect answers will show the correct answer).

I have tried doing some research but didn't find anything too helpful. I am relatively new to coding so any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
let score = 0;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let questions = [
  {
    title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
    answers: ['7','10','11','13'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
    answers: ['Dunder Mifflin','Ravenclaw','Slytherin','Gryffindor'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid','Albus Dumbledore','Severus Snaoe','Minerva McGonnagle'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
    answers: ['France','USA','UK','New Zealand'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
    answers: ['Stag','Eagle','Bear','Dragon'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
    answers: ['Dog','Owl','Cat','Snake'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
    answers: ['Remus Lupin','Siruis Black','Lucious Malfoy','Severus Snape'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
    answers: ['Elder Wand','Cloak of Invisibility','Resurrection Stone','Sword of Gryffindor'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Slytherin','Ravenclaw','Gryffindor','Hufflepuff'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
    answers: ['Love','Anger','Friendship','Joy'],
    correct: 0
  },
];



$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.start a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.start').hide();
    $('.quiz').show();
    showQuestion();
  });
  
  $('.quiz ul').on('click','li',function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
  
  $('.quiz a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('li.selected').length){
      let guess = parseInt($('li.selected').attr('id'));
      checkAnswer(guess);
    } else {
      alert('Please select an answer');
    }
  });
  
  $('.summary a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    restartQuiz();
    
  });
  
});




function showQuestion(){
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
  $('.quiz ul').html('');
  for(var i=0; i<question.answers.length; i++){
    $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
  }
}

function checkAnswer(guess) {
    let question = questions[currentQuestion];
    if(question.correct === guess){
      score++;
    }
  currentQuestion++;
  if(currentQuestion >= questions.length){
    showSummary();
  } else {
  showQuestion();
  }
}

function showSummary(){
  $('.quiz').hide();
  $('.summary').show();
  $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered "+score+" out of "+questions.length+" correctly! Care to try again?")
}

function restartQuiz(){
  $('.summary').hide();
    $('.quiz').show();
    score = 0;
    currentQuestion = 0;
    showQuestion();
}
```

```css
.quiz, .summary {
  display: none;
}

.quiz ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.quiz li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  <div class = "start">
    <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?<h1>
    <h2>Take this short quiz to find out!<h2>
    <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
  </div>
      
  
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Choice</li>
        <li>Choice</li>
        <li>Choice</li>
        <li>Choice</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#">Submit Answer</a>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="summary">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
    <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
  </div>
      
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad at the moment. You have three questions there, so you should ask 3 separate questions and be more specific about each of them. Ask 1 Question about feed back to the  answer, being specific about what aspect of this you are having trouble with. Ask 1 Question about the running total, again being specific about your issue. Finally ask 1 question about indicating the progress, you guessed it, again being specific.

Comment: This is way too much need to go through. Do keep in mind that the community would love to help you out. However as what Jon said, if you have multiple questions that are involved in different fields/parts, kindly separates it into different questions and be more specific. Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I won't repeat comments above, but the best advise is if a problem is too hard then solve a simpler one first. Meaning break down your code into bits you can test individually, and then bring them back together to make the full application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you should change your quiz class div like this

```
  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Choice</li>
        <li>Choice</li>
        <li>Choice</li>
        <li>Choice</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#">Submit Answer</a>
      <div id="currentQuestion"></div> // these two divs are added
      <div id="isCorrect"></div> 
  </div>
```

and add some codes to javascript functions

refer to comments in the code

```
function showQuestion(){
let question = questions[currentQuestion];
    $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
    $('.quiz ul').html('');
    for(var i=0; i<question.answers.length; i++){
        $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
    }
    showProgress(); // everytime you show questions to also show progress
}

function checkAnswer(guess) {
    let question = questions[currentQuestion];
    if(question.correct === guess){ // when you check the answer you also show if it is correct also
        score++;
        showIsCorrect(true);
    }else{
        showIsCorrect(false);
    }

    currentQuestion++;
    if(currentQuestion >= questions.length){
        showSummary();
    } else {
        showQuestion();
    }
}

function showProgress(){ // this function shows the progress
    $('#currentQuestion').html(currentQuestion + " out of " + questions.length);
}

function showIsCorrect(isCorrect){ // this function shows if it is correct
    var result = "Wrong";
    if(isCorrect){
        result = "Correct";
    }
    $('#isCorrect').html(result);
}
```

like this

refer to code snippet

i want you to make this more delicate for practicing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .quiz,
    .summary {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .quiz ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .quiz li {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .selected {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="start">
    <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?
      <h1>
        <h2>Take this short quiz to find out!
          <h2>
            <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
  </div>


  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Submit Answer</a>
    <div id="currentQuestion"></div>
    <div id="isCorrect"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="summary">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
    <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    let score = 0;
    let currentQuestion = 0;
    let questions = [{
        title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
        answers: ['7', '10', '11', '13'],
        correct: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
        answers: ['Dunder Mifflin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Slytherin', 'Gryffindor'],
        correct: 0
      },
      {
        title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
        answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid', 'Albus Dumbledore', 'Severus Snaoe', 'Minerva McGonnagle'],
        correct: 3
      },
      {
        title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
        answers: ['France', 'USA', 'UK', 'New Zealand'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
        answers: ['Stag', 'Eagle', 'Bear', 'Dragon'],
        correct: 0
      },
      {
        title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
        answers: ['Dog', 'Owl', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
        correct: 1
      },
      {
        title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
        answers: ['Remus Lupin', 'Siruis Black', 'Lucious Malfoy', 'Severus Snape'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
        answers: ['Elder Wand', 'Cloak of Invisibility', 'Resurrection Stone', 'Sword of Gryffindor'],
        correct: 3
      },
      {
        title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
        answers: ['Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff'],
        correct: 2
      },
      {
        title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
        answers: ['Love', 'Anger', 'Friendship', 'Joy'],
        correct: 0
      },
    ];



    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.start a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.start').hide();
        $('.quiz').show();
        showQuestion();
      });

      $('.quiz ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
      });

      $('.quiz a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('li.selected').length) {
          let guess = parseInt($('li.selected').attr('id'));
          checkAnswer(guess);
        } else {
          alert('Please select an answer');
        }
      });

      $('.summary a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        restartQuiz();
      });

    });

    function showQuestion() {
      let question = questions[currentQuestion];
      $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
      $('.quiz ul').html('');
      for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
        $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
      }
      showProgress();
    }

    function checkAnswer(guess) {
      let question = questions[currentQuestion];
      if (question.correct === guess) {
        score++;
        showIsCorrect(true);
      } else {
        showIsCorrect(false);
      }

      currentQuestion++;
      if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
        showSummary();
      } else {
        showQuestion();
      }
    }

    function showSummary() {
      $('.quiz').hide();
      $('.summary').show();
      $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered " + score + " out of " + questions.length + " correctly! Care to try again?")
    }

    function restartQuiz() {
      $('.summary').hide();
      $('.quiz').show();
      score = 0;
      currentQuestion = 0;
      showQuestion();
    }

    function showProgress() {
      $('#currentQuestion').html(currentQuestion + " out of " + questions.length);
    }

    function showIsCorrect(isCorrect) {
      var result = "Wrong";
      if (isCorrect) {
        result = "Correct";
      }
      $('#isCorrect').html(result);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a counter within the code to go along with your quiz.

```
function checkAnswer(guess) {
let question = questions[currentQuestion];
<!-- Add Count Increase Here -->
if(question.correct === guess){
  score++;
}
//... Etc...
```

In this area I would increment the count variable.

And in your reset function I would reset this count variable.

Overall how you display the count variable is up to you. Just use a JS fill of an element such as this

HTML Element
    `<p class="count">0</p>`

JS To Fill That Element

`document.querySelector('.count').textContent = countVariableValue;`

If you need help building those pieces, let me know and I'll go deeper. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let score = 0;
let currentQuestion = 0;
let questions = [{
    title: "At what age was Harry Potter when he received his Hogwarts letter?",
    answers: ['7', '10', '11', '13'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Which is not a Hogwarts house?",
    answers: ['Dunder Mifflin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Slytherin', 'Gryffindor'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "Who teaches Transfiguration at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Rubeus Hagrid', 'Albus Dumbledore', 'Severus Snaoe', 'Minerva McGonnagle'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Where is Hogwarts School for Witchcraft and Wizardry located?",
    answers: ['France', 'USA', 'UK', 'New Zealand'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What form does Harry Potter's patronus charm take?",
    answers: ['Stag', 'Eagle', 'Bear', 'Dragon'],
    correct: 0
  },
  {
    title: "What type of animal is Harry's pet?",
    answers: ['Dog', 'Owl', 'Cat', 'Snake'],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Who is not a member of the Order of the Phoenix?",
    answers: ['Remus Lupin', 'Siruis Black', 'Lucious Malfoy', 'Severus Snape'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What is not a piece of the Deathly Hallows?",
    answers: ['Elder Wand', 'Cloak of Invisibility', 'Resurrection Stone', 'Sword of Gryffindor'],
    correct: 3
  },
  {
    title: "In which house is Harry sorted into after arriving at Hogwarts?",
    answers: ['Slytherin', 'Ravenclaw', 'Gryffindor', 'Hufflepuff'],
    correct: 2
  },
  {
    title: "What prevented Voldemort from being able to kill Harry Potter when he was a baby?",
    answers: ['Love', 'Anger', 'Friendship', 'Joy'],
    correct: 0
  },
];



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.start a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.start').hide();
    $('.quiz').show();
    showQuestion();
  });

  $('.quiz ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $('.quiz a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('li.selected').length) {
      let guess = parseInt($('li.selected').attr('id'));
      checkAnswer(guess);
    } else {
      alert('Please select an answer');
    }
  });

  $('.summary a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    restartQuiz();

  });

});




function showQuestion() {
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  $('.quiz h2').text(question.title);
  $('.quiz ul').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    $('.quiz ul').append(`<li id="${i}">${question.answers[i]}</li>`);
  }
  $('#stats').show();
  $('#current-question-count').text(currentQuestion + 1);
  $('#total-question-count').text(questions.length);
  $('#current-score-count').text(score);
  $('#total-score-count').text(currentQuestion);
}

function checkAnswer(guess) {
  let question = questions[currentQuestion];
  if (question.correct === guess) {
    score++;
  }
  $('#current-score-count').text(score);
  currentQuestion++;
  $('#total-score-count').text(currentQuestion);
  if (currentQuestion >= questions.length) {
    showSummary();
  } else {
    showQuestion();
  }
}

function showSummary() {
  $('.quiz').hide();
  $('.summary').show();
  $('.summary p').text("Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered " + score + " out of " + questions.length + " correctly! Care to try again?")
}

function restartQuiz() {
  $('.summary').hide();
  $('.quiz').show();
  score = 0;
  currentQuestion = 0;
  showQuestion();
}
```

```css
.quiz,
.summary,
#stats {
  display: none;
}

.quiz ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.quiz li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stats">
    <div id="question">
      You are currently on question
      <span id="current-question-count"></span> out of
      <span id="total-question-count"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="score">
      Your current score is
      <span id="current-score-count"></span> correct out of
      <span id="total-score-count"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="start">
    <h1>How Well Do You Know Harry Potter?
      <h1>
        <h2>Take this short quiz to find out!
          <h2>
            <a href="#">Start Quiz</a>
  </div>


  <div class="quiz">
    <h2>Question Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
      <li>Choice</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#">Submit Answer</a>
  </div>


  <div class="summary">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <p>Thank you for taking the quiz! Here's how you scored. You answered x out of y correctly! Care to try again?</p>
    <a href="#">Retake Quiz</a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions along with your code as clarification according to what you've provided that may suits for the answer. So new starter would not get confused/misled. Regards.